# Comparing Timestamp in Drools

Tags: drools

I have a class as below:

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;

class Order{
  private Timestamp orderDate;
  private boolean valid = true;
  // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

I'm passing this object to Drools from another class:

```
class Caller{
  Order order = new Order();
  order.setOrderDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
  ...
  kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
  kSession.execute(oInfo);
}
```

Now, if the orderDate is greater than 30 days, I need to set "valid" to false. My drools file template is below:

```
package com.drools.rules

//list any import classes here.
import com.test.Order;


//declare any global variables here


rule "Order date checker"

    when
        $o : Order(orderDate <What should I put here?>)
    then
        $o.setValid(false);

end
```

Comment: Do you mean "if the orderDate is farther back than 30 days from now"? (A Date or Timestamp cannot be compared to an interval.)

Answer (score 1):

Insert a Timestamp equal to "now - 30 days".

```
Date deadline = new Date( new Date().getTime() - 30L*24*60*60*1000 );
ksession.insert( deadline );
```

And then you can compare dates to now-30d:

```
rule isDue
when
  $d: Date()
  Foo( $name: name, date < $d )
then
  System.out.println( "overdue: " + $name );
end
```

You are using Timestamp, however, so you'll have to write a little more code:

```
Date( $t: time )
$o : Order(orderDate.getTime() < $t)
```

**Later**

You can insert the Date object in a rule. Just make sure it is fired with maximum priority:

```
rule "set Date"
salience Integer.MAX_VALUE
when
then
    Date deadline = new Date( new Date().getTime() - 30L*24*60*60*1000 );
    insert( deadline );
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to declare the Timestamp directly in drools.drl file? The reason why I'm asking is I have multiple customers, and each have different rules files and different dates. I do not want to put if / else conditions in Java to add different dates for different retailers.

Comment: Added a rule to insert Date from DRL.